# How to randomly alter an array based on an if statement as if mutating a gene in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, random, genetic-algorithm, mutation

mutation_rate=.05 and current_pop is an array. How can I make this if statement randomly change values within the array? This is mutation in a genetic algorithm. Thanks for the help!

```
    for i in range(len(current_pop)):
        r= np.random.rand() 
        if r < mutation_rate: 

    return new_array
```

`

Answer (score 0):

current_pop[i] = random.randint(min_val, max_val)

You should define min and max vals.